# Excel 2007 shadow copy?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, add-in

My question is about Excel add-ins and VBA code.

This is the situation:

There are 2 Excel files; one is just a normal Excel sheet, one is a .xla add-in with VBA code which is stored on a network drive.

In the normal Excel sheet is a reference to the .xla file so that the sheet can use the macros from the .xla file. This works fine so far, but sometimes there seems to be a bug: It looks likes the sheet uses some kind of "shadow copy" of the .xla file.
The bug occurs when I change code in the VBA editor or I set a breakpoint, both are ignored when running the macro. It feels like there is a old copy of the .xla file, which is invisible and which is somehow stored in the normal Excel file, so the code running is not the macro I see in the editor.

I think this problem has occurred since I installed MS Office 2007.

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be surprised if Excel is storing a version of your add-in locally.  When making a change to your xla, I would be sure to re-add your add-in to ensure the latest version is installed.

EDIT:

You could try doing something like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    AddIns("Your Library Name").Installed = False 'To remove current link
    AddIns.Add Filename = "\\Your Server Path\Excel_Library3.xla"
    AddIns("Your Library Name").Installed = True

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

That would make sure the latest addin is loaded from your network location when they open the excel sheet.

Comment: that could be possible. But why is Excel doing this sometimes and sometimes not? How can i prevent it from doing this? About 50 people are using the referenced xla file. I cant let them manuelly re-add the add-in each time. Some of them don´t even know what a addin is :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than referencing the file I load the addin's via code.  My use is to store my addins in my Dropbox folder but a network would work the same.

```
Sub LoadAddins()

Dim wbOpen As Workbook
Dim wbNew As Workbook
Dim strAddinsPath As String
Dim strExtension As String

On Error Resume Next

strAddinsPath = "\\Server\Excel\AddIns\" 'Your server path here

ChDir strAddinsPath

strExtension = Dir("*.xlam")

        Do While strExtension <> ""
            Set wbOpen = Workbooks.Open(strAddinsPath & strExtension)
            strExtension = Dir
        Loop

On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

You need to add it as a trusted location but lets me put any addin's I'm working on in the folder and having them auto load.

The code to iterate through files in a folder I modified from:
http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/2007-filesearch-alternative.htm